# How do I use 'this' as a parameter to another object?

Tags: java, reference, parameter-passing, this

First of I know this must be simple and I've been trying to read similar questions here, on Stackoverflow.com, and Google, but I still can't get my program to work.

I've quickly written an abstract of what my program is trying to do:

```
    public class One{

    public One(){
        Two t = new Two(this);
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        sout("HERE");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        One o = new One()
        Two t = new Two(o);
    }

}

    public class Two{

        public Two(One o){
            One o = o;
            o.doSomething();
        }
    }
```

When I run the program, I get a NullPointerException, from the method call o.doSomething(). I've have been trying for a while to fix it, but I'm stumped. If anyone could quickly tell me the fix it'll go greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual line in `doSomething` that NPEs?

Comment: @BrendanLong An IntelliJ shortcut :p

Comment: Should  be a lazy way of saying `System.out.println();`

Comment: can you show us the `sout` methode ?

Comment: `One o = o` will not compile.

Comment: pleas past the code with you compiled to a runnable class

Comment: I have just tested the program and it worked, but when I make a thread and pass this, it messes up :S

Comment: After debugging, it seems this is actually working, what made me assume this wasn't working was I was calling a method from a thread which produces a nullpointerexception. This issue isn't fixed, however the question I have asked was not the issue, could a moderator please close this.

Comment: You're passing this to a new object Two that calls back on this.  This hasn't fully initialized yet as the constructor hasn't finished. Be careful.

Answer (score 5):

```
One o = o;
```

I have no idea what this is meant to do, but it won't work. Is this supposed to be a member variable (`this.o`)? To do that, put it in the class instead of the function:

```
public class Two{
    private One o;

    public Two(One o){
        this.o = o;
        o.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Or remove it entirely if you don't need it:

```
public class Two{
    public Two(One o){
        o.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `sout("HERE")` does not exists. If you are trying to print something to console, you should use `System.out.println("HERE")`.

Comment: As a comment indicated, this is probably a shortcut of the particular IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your class please check I think it should work

public class One{

```
public One(){
    Two t = new Two(this);
}

public void doSomething(){
    System.out.println("HERE");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    One o = new One();
    Two t = new Two(o);
}
```

}

```
public class Two{

    public Two(One one){
        One o = one; //just changed the parameter name to one
        o.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "this" word is used when you want to refer to the current object; in addition you can use "this.something" when you want to access the variable "something" of the current object.

For instance, you can insert it in your code to distinguish the "this.o" (property of the object) from the "o" (input argument):

```
import java.io.*;


public class One{
    public One(){
        Two t = new Two(this);
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("HERE");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        One o = new One();
        Two t = new Two(o);
    }
}


public class Two{
    One o;

    public Two(One o){
        this.o = o;
        this.o.doSomething();
    }
}
```

This will compile and produce an output:

HERE
HERE

Is that what you want?

Comment: I built the program literally 5 minutes ago and that's exactly what I got. In my actual program, I'm passin this to a thread. I'm about to debug it now, by adding a toString method in the object I'm trying to send and System.Out the object in the thread.